# How to map a String to an int according to a mapping structure

Tags: java

This question is probably basic but I am still struggling to solve this.
I need to implement a method that gets a `String` and gives back the according `int` according to a list.
For example:

```
Christmas = 10
Holiday = 11
```

..

```
String text = {Christmas Holiday}
```

`public static int StringtoInt (String text)` shall be able to scan through the `String` and map the strings according to the provided list.

Could someone provide me with a hint how to solve this.

Comment: Use a map to map the string to an int?

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-map

Comment: what is the expected output and input ? and where is your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HashMap<String, Integer>` for this purpose:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

myMap.put("Christmas", 10);
myMap.put("Holyday", 11);
```

and you can retrieve the int mapped to a `String` via

```
myMap.get("Christmas");
```

See more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).